# Application support iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios7

My application supports both iOS 6 and 7, is there anyway load images automatically from xib  files or code depending on images name, like to differentiate between iPhone and iPad I add ~ipad or ~iphone, and the corresponding file will automatically loaded.

and if there is no such a method like this, what is the easiest way to load different resources for each one.

Thanks

Comment: you mean load image based on IOS6 or 7?

Comment: yes, or any other file, like xib files?

Comment: I dont think if there is away to do something like you can do for ipad nad iphone. detect the version and do your stuff, if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

No, see Apple's provided iOS transition guide where they say you must manage it yourself and provide a snippet for determining the iOS version before loading assets.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1